# How to create a menu in a spreadsheet outside of onOpen()? (Google Apps Script)

Tags: variables, caching, drop-down-menu, google-apps-script

I'm trying to **create a menu in a spreadsheet** without opening it. I've done it before within the onOpen() function but now I'm trying to do it within a normal function. With this script I can create a file but it won't create my "actions" menu in the file.

```
function Frank_PersistentVariable(){
//create file ID
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create("TEST").getId();
//clean cache of file IDs
  CacheService.getPrivateCache().remove('cachedObject');
//load file ID to cache
  CacheService.getPrivateCache().put('cachedObject', ss);
}

function Frank_Menu(){ 
//create menu  
      var menu = [
      {name: "action1", functionName: "MyFunction1"},
      {name: "action2", functionName: "MyFunction2"},
      {name: "action3", functionName: "MyFunction3"},
      ];
//call file ID from cache
  var cachedObject = CacheService.getPrivateCache().get('cachedObject');
//call file using ID
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(cachedObject);
//display menu in file
  ss.addMenu("actions", menu);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, the menu will be created only when the function `Frank_Menu` is run. When are you running this function? Are you running it manually after opening the spreadsheet ?

Comment: Responding to this past answer: I am aware that the menu will be created only when the function Frank_Menu is run, but even so it doesn't work. I am running the function from a **blank project** separate from the spreadsheet. This is my problem, I want to call a spreadsheet using openById() and then create a menu. But so far the only way that I am able to create a menu is if I do it from the back end of a spreadsheet under an onOpen() function.